# "Failed opening required file" in consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to implement consolibyte/quickbooks-php in my Laravel 5.5 project but it's a bit difficult as the instructions are a little vague from this (as well as from Laravel 5.2 so I'm not sure how much has changed) (http://lamparchitect.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-implement-quickbooks-online-api.html).

I receive this error after following the instructions:

```
QuickBooks_Loader::load(): Failed opening required 'E:\webserver\htdocs\truckin\vendor\consolibyte\quickbooks/QuickBooks\Driver\.php' (include_path='E:\webserver\php\PEAR;E:\webserver\htdocs\truckin\vendor\consolibyte\quickbooks')
```

This specific line it is referring to is here:

```
if (QUICKBOOKS_LOADER_REQUIREONCE)
        {
            require_once QUICKBOOKS_BASEDIR . $file;
        }
```

But I'm not sure where $file is defined given that I followed the instructions and it isn't defined anywhere in there.

I'm not sure where to go from here. The project I am working on requires Intuit integration, so I'm not sure if there is a better way or not on the integration itself.

Comment: Intuit has it's own [PHP SDK](https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK).

Comment: Post your code. If you don't post your code, we can't see what you're doing and can't help you. More than likely you're missing a $dsn string.

Comment: @user320487 the PHP SDK Inuit created is for Quickbooks Online only, what OP is building is relative to Quickbooks Desktop. Two completely separate applications with separate integration points.